# How can get the pdf url docusign Php Api

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using the php Api for docusign . Got it from [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client). What i want is to get the url of the signed DOC . Is it possible to get that. ?I am using the following code.

```
 $username = $option['docu_username'];
    $password =$option['docu_pass'];
    $integrator_key = $option['docu_integrator_key'];
    $host = $option['docu_host'];
    // create a new DocuSign configuration and assign host and header(s)
    $config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
    $config->setHost($host);
    $config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . $username . "\",\"Password\":\"" . $password . "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . $integrator_key . "\"}");
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1:  Login() API
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // instantiate a new docusign api client
    $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
    // we will first make the Login() call which exists in the AuthenticationApi...
    $authenticationApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi($apiClient);
    // optional login parameters
    $options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
    // call the login() API
    $loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);
    // parse the login results
    if(isset($loginInformation) && count($loginInformation) > 0)
    {
        // note: defaulting to first account found, user might be a 
        // member of multiple accounts
        $loginAccount = $loginInformation->getLoginAccounts()[0];
        if(isset($loginInformation))
        {
            $accountId = $loginAccount->getAccountId();
        }
    }
    if(empty($accountId))
    {
        return false;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 2:  Create & Send Envelope (aka Signature Request)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // set recipient information

    // instantiate a new envelopeApi object
    $envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
    // Add a document to the envelope
    $document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
    $document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents($documentFileName)));
    $document->setName($documentName);
    $document->setDocumentId("1");
    // Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
    $signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
    $signHere->setXPosition("20");
    $signHere->setYPosition("20");
    $signHere->setDocumentId("1");
    $signHere->setPageNumber("1");
    $signHere->setRecipientId("1");
    // add the signature tab to the envelope's list of tabs
    $tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
    $tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere));
    // add a signer to the envelope
    $signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
    $signer->setEmail($recipientEmail);
    $signer->setName($recipientName);
    $signer->setRecipientId("1");
    $signer->setClientUserId('12345');
    $signer->setTabs($tabs);
    // Add a recipient to sign the document
    $recipients = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients();
    $recipients->setSigners(array($signer));
    $envelop_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
    $envelop_definition->setEmailSubject("Please sign this doc");
    // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
    $envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");
    $envelop_definition->setRecipients($recipients);
    $envelop_definition->setDocuments(array($document));
    // create and send the envelope! (aka signature request)
    $envelop_summary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition, null);
$viewrequest = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest();
        $viewrequest->setUserName($recipientName); 
        $viewrequest->setEmail($recipientEmail);
        $viewrequest->setRecipientId(1);
        $viewrequest->setClientUserId('12345');
        $viewrequest->setAuthenticationMethod('email');
        $viewrequest->setReturnUrl($ReturnUrl);
        $envelopview=$envelopeApi->createRecipientView($accountId,$document->envelopeId,$viewrequest);
        $redirecturl=$envelopview->getUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You can list an envelope's documents and get it too.

Take a look at `listDocuments` and `getDocument` methods. I don't program in PHP so I can't provide you examples, but just checked the [GitHub PHP SDK repo](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/Api/EnvelopesApi.php) and its available too.

By the way, using the REST API directly there is `/accounts/{{accid}}/envelopes/{{envid}}/documents/combined` endpoint that provides you all documents of an envelope in a single PDF, but I couldn't find anything similar into the SDK (neither in Java or PHP).

Hope it helps!

Comment: not getting the doc pdf . Any guess how can i do that ?

Comment: @Ergin answer complements my answer. You need to get the bytes and convert it to your PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @jfneis mentioned, you need to use the `getDocument()` API to retrieve the actual signed document bytes for an envelope.  Before you do that though, you make the `listDocuments()` request to get the actual document endpoints for downloading each doc.

Note that each endpoint to download envelope docs will contain the `documentId` as part of the URL.  So if you have envelope "AAA" with two documents (IDs 1001 and 1002), for example, to download them you would do:

```
GET v2/accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/documents/1001
GET v2/accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/documents/1002
```